# Generalised Rolle's theorem

Tags: calculus

What is generalised Rolle's theorem in simple words?

I know that the theorem is- 
If $F:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is a function such that the $(n-1)$-th derivative of $F$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$. If $F(x)$ has $n+1$ roots in $[a,b]$ then there exists $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that the $n$-th derivative of $F(x)$ at $x=c$ is zero.

I didn't really understand this. Can this theorem be simplified more. 
I know Rolle's theorem but I am confused in its generalization.

Comment: check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259621/generalized-rolles-theorem-confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple consequence of the regular Rolle's Theorem.

If $\{x_i\}_{i=0}^n$ are the $n+1$ roots of $F$ in increasing order, then Rolle's theorem can be applied to each of the $n$ intervals $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ for $i \ge 1$. On each of these intervals, there must be a value $x_i'$ such that $F'(x_i') = 0$. So $F'$ has to have at least $n$ zeros. The same argument applied to $F'$ instead of $F$ shows that $F''$ has at least $n-1$ zeros. Continuing in the same fashion, we get

- $F'''$ has at least $n-2$ zeros,
- $F^{(4)}$ has at least $n-3$ zeros,
- ...
- $F^{(n-1)}$ has at least $2$ zeros,
- $F^{(n)}$ has at least $1$ zero.

Which is the conclusion of the generalized theorem.

Comment: This proof made the theorem easy to understand. Thanks.